# How to add a shape into a powerpoint layout

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-2013

I am trying to lock a shape in PowerPoint by putting it into the layout. And after I am doing necessary my stuff, I want to unlock the shape by putting the shape out of the layout.

I can add a shape to layout from the menu. But there is no way to put the shape out of the Layout except implementing "undo" action.

[image]

Another thing is I don't know how to make it programmatically in code.

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2013, PowerPoint 2013, C#

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this cases is to record a new macro and make the desired actions in the UI. Then I stop recording and go to see the code created in VB. Then is just a mater of to translate to c#

Comment: can you give me a link of how to use macro?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-a-macro-HP003089016.aspx

Comment: I've never used macro in vsto before, and don't know what is it for? Could you explain a little bit? I am curious about recording macro.

Comment: @chipbk10 Just read the documentation at MSDN. More usefull than my explanations.